# Proving a set $A$ is open

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

The question reads: Prove the set $A = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2: -1 < x < 0, -1 < y < 1\}$ is open in $\mathbb{R}^2$ with respect to the max metric, $d_m$.

Clearly this set forms a square with boundaries $y=1, y=-1, x = -1$, and $x=0$. We need to show that for all $(a,b) \in A$, there exists an open ball of radius $r$ around $(a,b)$, and that this open ball is contained in $A$.

My problems begin with my choice of $r$, and from there I'm not necessarily sure how to keep going. I set $r = \min\{ |-1-a|,|-1-b|,|1-b|,|a|\}$, but I cannot help but feel this is incorrect, and even if I do follow through with my choice, I'm struggling in proving it.

Comment: Your choice of $r$ is sufficient. Because  if $(c,d)\in B_{d_m}(\;(a,b),r)$ then $-1<a-r<c<a+r<0$ and $-1<b-r<d<b+r<1,$ so $(c,d)\in A.$

Comment: @DanielWainfleet this was the answer I was looking for. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Visually, under the $d_m$ metric, $B(p,r)$, an open ball of radius $r$, centered on point $p$, is an open square of side length $2r$ with edges parallel to the x and y axises, and the point $p$ in its center.

Using this idea, draw a picture, and it's clear that choosing $r=\min\{|1-x|,|-1-x|,|1-y|,|-1-y|\}$ would give you a square inside the big square.